# How to print content of multiple urls onto one single txt.file?

Tags: python-3.x, url, web-scraping, python-requests, read-text

Good afternoon, I am new to stack overflow so I apologize in advance if my question is not in the right format.

I have a list of URLs such as these (but many more),

```
master_urls = 
['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2020/QTR1/master.20190102.idx',
'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2020/QTR1/master.20190103.idx]
```

and I want to write the content onto one single txt.file.
Using one of these URLs works perfectly fine. I do the steps below to achieve it:

```
file_url = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2019/QTR2/master.20190401.idx"

content = requests.get(file_url).content

with open('master_20190401.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

The txt.file looks like this (this is just a small sample of the text file, but it's all the same as shown below just with different company names ...etc):

```
CIK|Company Name|Form Type|Date Filed|File Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|8-K|20190401|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-19-093800.txt
1000209|MEDALLION FINANCIAL CORP|SC 13D/A|20190401|edgar/data/1000209/0001193125-19-094732.txt
1000228|HENRY SCHEIN INC|4|20190401|edgar/data/1000228/0001209191-19-021970.txt
1000275|ROYAL BANK OF CANADA|424B2|20190401|edgar/data/1000275/0001140361-19-006199.txt
```

I tried the following code to get the content of all URLs onto one text file

```
for file in master_urls:
    content = requests.get(file).content
    with open('complete_list.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

but it does not work.

Can anyone help me get the content of each URL in my list of URLs onto one single text file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are opening your file inside the loop for every URL, the file is getting overwrriten.

try this :

```
with open('complete_list.txt', 'wb') as f:
  for url in master_urls:
     content = requests.get(url).content
     f.write(content)
```

Comment: I got the following error when trying that:

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: updated the answer. The file had to be opened with 'wb'.

Comment: I ran that code and opened the text file but it was full of the following text:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>44B5D4525BEAFE76</RequestId><HostId>ixubjAJdQUgGR2DPee+m213KKBrTN3zTHTxIRC2VtrHOKx91O0XVsM5oU2uMi6xFISeuuBbSDxA=</HostId></Error><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: you'll have to check if those url are correct. since those are not accessible even via the browser. only url working is  https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2019/QTR2/master.20190401.idx